# Searching for a value/string and aditional endings in another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use each value/string in a certain column (A1, A2, A3...) in worksheet 1 to search a certain range in worksheet 2 for that value/string alone and (!) with additional endings.

Example: Use in worksheet 1 A1 = K-1234 and search in a defined range in worksheet 2 for the string K-1234 and combinations of K-1234 with /x, /y, /z. Whenever you find such a combination copy the whole row from worksheet 2 into a new worksheet 3.

**Using column A in worksheet 1:**

```
worksheet 1    

A

A1    = K-1234
A2    = Y-1234
A3    = RP-78
…
A1000 = Z/34-1
```

**Searching in worksheet 2 in the range B1:E3 for A1, A1/x, A1/y and A1/z:**

```
worksheet 2

A     B      C     D     E

GHJ   A1/x   456   G5G   F1-1
FF-   A1     23-A  TTR   BV1
8/a   A1/z   bnR   34-1  bn/1
```

**That's how worksheet 3 should look like after using A1 from worksheet 1 to search in worksheet 2:**

```
worksheet 3

A     B     C      D      E 

FF-   A1    23-A   TTR   BV1
GHJ   A1/x  456    G5G    F1-1
8/a   A1/z  bnR    34-1   bn/1
```

**or with A1 written out:**

```
worksheet 3

A     B          C      D      E 

FF-   K-1234     23-A   TTR   BV1
GHJ   K-1234/x   456    G5G    F1-1
8/a   K-1234/z   bnR    34-1   bn/1
```

(A1/y doesn't exist)

Continue with A2, A2/x, A2/y and A2/z and so on till the end of the column (for example A1000).

Hope I could explain the problem sufficiently. I would be very thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: Why can't you solve this issue? Where exactly did you get stuck? What was your attempt? What is your question? You didn't ask one yet. • Because this is no free coding service you must include the code you have tried and explain where you got stuck or errors. • Please read [ask] to improve your question.

Comment: You have `vba` as a tag.. thus I assume you want some code to help.. Please provide what you have already so we can help you where you are getting stuck...

Comment: Hello! Sorry, but I'm really knew to programming and VBA which is why I'm asking this question without giving some code. I'm trying to teach myself VBA and Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyYes()

    Dim i As Long, LastRow1 As Long, LastRow3 As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim rngToSearch As Range, rngFound As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set ws3 = .Worksheets("Sheet3")
    End With

    Set rngToSearch = ws2.Range("B1:E3")

    With ws1

        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow1

            Set rngFound = rngToSearch.Find(.Range("A" & i).Value & "*", LookIn:=xlValues)

            If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then

                LastRow3 = ws3.Cells(ws3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                If LastRow3 = 1 And ws3.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
                    LastRow3 = 1
                Else
                    LastRow3 = LastRow3 + 1
                End If

                ws2.Range("B" & rngFound.Row & ":E" & rngFound.Row).Copy
                ws3.Range("A" & LastRow3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work for me. It doesn't show me any errors. Nothing happens.

Comment: Hello. What do you mean with debugging? He doesn't show me any errors. There is no debugging pop up. Nothing happens.

Comment: insert a break point in the first line and go through code using F8 to find what is going wrong using immediate and watches windows.

Comment: Okay, I will try it out. Thank you.